Expo React Native - Adding node_modules/react-native/cli.js. node_modules/react-native already exists in the file map as a file
I installed a NPM package, which then seemed to mess up my dependency environment, causing my app to crash on launch with the error:
Error: TreeFS: Could not add directory node_modules/react-native, adding node_modules/react-native/cli.js. node_modules/react-native already exists in the file map as a file.

I tried several times to delete the node_modules folder and npm install again, but this did not fix the issue. I am now unable to get my app to start.

I managed to fix the issue by following these steps:

Shut down the application server (I was running it with npx expo start, so
I just used Ctrl-C)
Clean the NPM cache with npm cache clean --force
Remove the node_modules folder (rm -fr node_modules in the project root), and also delete package-lock.json
Reboot your computer (this was a necessary step for me)
Open the project and do npm install.

After following these steps, I was able to run my app again!

this didn't work for me.
everything was fine today and then suddenly i started getting this error.
i have reverted to previous versions of my package.json and nothing seem to work.
i'm super stuck. my blood is boiling!

finally it worked. apparently has to do with installing packages with "pnpm". finally fixed by doing the computer reset in the middle as you suggested. weird. started happening just today.
